# vb NET designer file

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have a dataset file called `dsmaster` in A program,and i am trying to create another B program using the same dataset, so i am just adding the dataset as a link to the B program. However i noticed that in the B program it will generate another designer file call `dsmaster1.desingner.vb` while `dsmaster.designer.vb` is exists located in `dsmaster.vb`

this is the new file tree

```
dsmaster.xsd
|-dsmaster.vb
| |-dsmaster.Designer.vb
| |-dsmaster
|-dsmaster.xsc
|-dsmaster.xss
|-dsmaster1.Designer.vb
  |-dsmaster
```

how come the visual will generate another designer file and the original designer file was put in the `dsmaster.vb`

in the program A the file tree looks like

```
dsmaster.xsd
    |-dsmaster.vb
    | |-dsmaster
    |-dsmaster.xsc
    |-dsmaster.xss
    |-dsmaster.Designer.vb
      |-dsmaster
```

Comment: I've never tried this but if you're sharing pieces of the code between projects then I'd suggest separating the common code into a library and referencing that from both.

Comment: actually this is not a different program, i am just creating a master program which will contain all code  and a child program that will only contain some code from the master code due to the customization for each customer, so i have to keep the master program or i have to say the default program and just add the code/module/form that can be used by the child program.

Comment: Even easier then, just add a reference to you master project from your child project. Then you can use any of the master classes (as long as they're declared public).